# ActionPerformed and ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, parseint

My program asks the user: How many course have you completed? So, the users has to enter the number of courses completed on a JTextField component. My program then converts the String that has been entered in the JTextField into a Integer. When I run my program, I get a numberformatException. I tried debugging, and I noticed that my program converts the String into a Integer before the user can write anything. The program doesn't wait for the user to type anything. How can I make so my program waits for the user to enter a number before continuing to execute the code?

```
public class content extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

     String number = "";
     JTextField NumtextField = new JTextField(5);

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         number = NumtextField.getNumtextField().getText();
     }

     int size = Integer.parseInt(number);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at JFormattedField, JSpinner and/or DocumentFilter

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. As to your problem: the snippet you are showing doesn't explain the problem you describe - show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `int size = Integer.parseInt(number);` inside actionPerformed:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 number = NumtextField.getNumtextField().getText();
 int size = Integer.parseInt(number);
 }
```

When the program starts, its trying to parse `""`, which is not a valid number string hence why you are getting an exception.
Also maybe you should put that inside a try{}catch{} block, so in case you get an exception in real time you can handle it:

```
try {
 int size = Integer.parseInt(number);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
System.out.println("Thats not a valid number");
}
```

Comment: It has solved the error problem, but my program still runs without the user's input, because it doesn't wait for the user to enter the number of course completed. How can I make make the program wait ?

Comment: `but my program still runs without the user's input` == use `JOptionPane` and use `JFormattedTextField` instead of parsing whatever from plain `JTextField`

Comment: @mKorbel  How can I make my program wait for the user to enter the number before continuing?

Comment: @Pierre the action event should only happen when the object to which its attached fires an ActionEvent, what do you mean wait for the user's input?

Comment: @MrD In fact, my program takes the user's input (the number entered in the JTextField) and does some calculation. So, if my code doesnt wait for the user's number, it is calculating with no numbers.

Comment: then you need to prevent that code from getting excecuted, possibly move it inside actionPerformed aswell, chances are you are doing that in the main method, aren't you?

Comment: @MrD Well, my program does a lot of thing after. It create an array of the size of the user's input then asks the name of all the completed courses. So it woulnd't be a good way to code it that way. :S

Comment: You are not coding right, all of those things should be inside methods, then you can call them when its appropriate

Comment: @MrD My actionPeformed isnt in my main method.

Comment: @Pierre jFrame is a method? Regarless, you have objects, classes, methods and events confused the point is thats not Object Oriented, you shouldn't be creating a sequence of commands and then running them in order, you should create classes with methods that. Anyway I think the original question was answered either way so if thats the case please mark a correct answer and if you have any further questions, you can always ask more, I'd offer you to live chat but you don't have enough reputation to do so, here is my email if you need any more help Mister_Dee@outlook.com

Comment: @MrD I didn't say that jFrame was a method... And I have objects, classes and methods in my program. I have to learn about events because I'm confused. Anyhow, thanks for your help